# How to drag and drop items between FlatLists on React Native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I am developing react native app like photo below. I have a positions flatlist. Each Positions item has orange point which is drag and drop and can add to timeline area. I am using "react-native-draggable" package. But I can not drag orange point out of the flatlist. Also positions flatlist can be reorder in my scenario and delete items when I move to trash.

I know it's a very common scenario but as I'm quite new to React-Native so I am struggling to get any library or create the same by myself.

[My scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMFht.png)

I will be glad if you can help

Comment: Try https://github.com/mochixuan/react-native-drag-sort

Answer (score -1):

try this package https://github.com/computerjazz/react-native-draggable-flatlist hope it will solve your problem

Comment: No can't, I tried this. I can't move orange point out of flatlist

Comment: FWIW I think the basic example in rndf just shows the list ... it's the swipable list in the example that lets you move things